# Dual Monitor support without external video card

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, hdmi

I'm thinking about buying a MBP Retina 13".

Now I want to work at home on 2 Monitors, so the MBP will be somewhere under the table.
Is it possible to connect first Monitor via HDMI and the other one via Thunderbolt/MiniDP Adapter to DVI.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are some people here at my office that are doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so.

See this [MacRumors forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1565031) for a user with a similar need.

Sadly, I don't have a 13" Retina MacBook to test with.